# Is or was? Which one is suitable?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, american-english, relative-clauses, future-constructions

I have question about is or was this this situation. Please help me!

1. The museum I went to yesterday is very beautiful.
2. The museum I went to yesterday was very beautiful.
   Which one is correct?
   Thank you very much!

Comment: Neither is strictly 'wrong', but it makes sense to use (1), because presumably the museum hasn't become ugly since yesterday.

Comment: I think so too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but they convey slightly different meanings.

"The museum I went to yesterday is very beautiful." - This sentence implies that the museum is still beautiful today, and it emphasizes the ongoing state of the museum's beauty.

"The museum I went to yesterday was very beautiful." - This sentence is focused on the beauty you experienced during your visit yesterday, and it emphasizes the beauty at that specific moment in the past.

That being said, in my opinion, the difference is irrelevant, and you could go with either of the two sentences.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much Mephisto!